# Do graves decay?

Tags: banished

I have a graveyard to bury my dead in, and although I'm pretty sure it was full earlier, it now has four empty plots. Do the graves eventually decay, or did I just look at it wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Graves will decay over time (after approximately a generation) to make room for more dead villagers.

Source: http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/Cemetery

Comment: But how long does a grave actually take to decay?

Comment: It's in the link. Added it to my answer (assuming the wiki is correct)